# Why are there so many USB connector types?

Tags: usb, connector

Why are there so many different [USB connector types](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB#Connector_types)?  Is it just that they've gotten smaller as Moore's Law progressed and there was a need for smaller connectors, or is there something more?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Cell phones were getting smaller and denser.  The space inside of the cell phone is at a premium. Two times that has pushed the size of the connector down: first to mini-, then to micro- .
   Notice that the Standard-A connector on the host-side has remained more a less unchanged.
2. New ramifications of USB have appeared: OTG and USB 3.0

Comment: Also the push from mini to micro was motivated by the mini wearing out and the plugs getting loose and falling out easily.  The micro was designed for more insertion removal cycles, 10k I think, and if you look closely you'll see the device ends have little raised teeth designed to give it more retention force.